# Implementing DatePicker in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, fragment

I'am using Fragment which is an instance of Fragment and not of DialogFragment.

I did google most of the search result shows how to use DialogFragment to have DatePicker.

which isn't working in my case because of type mismatch of Fragment and DialogFragment

Any example or idea would be helpful

**Here is the Fragment Java Code**

```
        public class CreateReportFragment extends Fragment {

        public CreateReportFragment(){}

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {

               rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_create_report, container, false);
               initViews();
               return rootView;
        }

        private void initViews() 
       {

         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
             month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
             day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

             editTextDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
             // Month is 0 based, just add 1
             .append(year)
             .append("-")
                    .append(month + 1)
                     .append("-").append(day));

        buttonDate = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDate);
        }
```

How to implement **DatePicker** in **Fragment**?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a `DialogFragment`

If i am guessing right you want to show a DatePicker on click of buttonDate

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

On Button click

```
DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

DatePickerFragment.java

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());    
}
}
```

Comment: where did **listener = (TheListener) getActivity();** come from?

Comment: @AndroidNewbie remove it it was a copy paste from one of my codes and i forgot to remove it

Comment: @AndroidNewbie you could use a interface as a callback to the activity and then communicate date to fragment. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @AndroidNewbie first look at the docs understand and give it a try. then if you have problems come back and post the updated code

Comment: Sir. Please? Im stuck here again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44508/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-androidnewbie)

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried your code its working fine, except for when i click button twice (in quick succession) i get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added` exception. How to stop it from showing twice?

Comment: @Kaustuv you can disable the button after first click and enable it later. Its upto you how you design

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i can disable the button on first click and enable it when i get a callback in onDateSet method. The problem is, in my device the date picker has a 'cancel' button. so when user clicks on cancel onDateSet method is not called. what to do?

Comment: @Kaustuv you can use interface as a callback to the activity and do what is required. Ask a new question instead of commenting here

Comment: @Raghunandan doing that only, onDateSet method calls a interface method to my fragment. but since onDateSet is not called (when cancel button of date picker is used), my fragment doesn't know when to enable back the button. if user click on 'set' button of date picker then all is fine. Is there any way to find if date picker fragment is already on screen or not? Something similar to like we can do on a listView.getAdapter ?

Comment: @Kaustuv ask a new question. i am not going to comment here anymore. good luck. Understand fragment and activity and do your design. Its a design issue. Do look at the fragment api's once. Have you done that??

Comment: please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779110/android-spinner-doesnt-showing-last-selected-item/

Comment: how can use the new value in the main fragment ? can i return it or something ?

Answer (score 5):

> How to implement DatePicker in Fragment?

The same way you would "implement" a `TextView` in a `Fragment`: have `onCreateView()` return a `View` that is or contains a `DatePicker`. For example, you might have a layout file that contains a `DatePicker` widget, and have `onCreateView()` inflate that layout.

Comment: but what i would like to happen is that when i click a button the datepicker will show.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie: And this is exactly what Mark said.

Answer (score 3):

> . . . which isn't working in my case because of type mismatch of Fragment and DialogFragment

A `DialogFragment` IS-A `Fragment` because it extends Fragment.Therefore, you can use a DialogFragment anywhere you would a Fragment.