# android - issues with datepicker within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I'm migrating activities to fragments and I'm having issues with a date picker dialog that worked fine on the old activity. I used this example: [Implementing DatePicker in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923604/implementing-datepicker-in-fragment) but I'm having issues sending the chosen date back to the fragment it's needed in. The "date picker" fragment is nested inside of the "general info" fragment. My goal here is to send the selected date from the DatePickerFragment to the GeneralInfoFragment.

Here's the code I have so far:

Listener for "choose date" button

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.myDatePickerButton:

            DialogFragment datepicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datepicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

            break;
}
```

DatePickerFragment.java

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(month, day, year);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        String outputDOI = formattedDate.toString(); // variable I want to send to GeneralInfoFragment

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting some error?May be you can post your error log?

Comment: @Sash_KP No errors, it just doesn't update on my "general info" fragment. The dialog opens and closes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, call the Fragment as shown below:

```
            DialogFragment timepicker = DialogFragment.newInstance(1);
            timepicker.setTargetFragment(GeneralInfoFragment.this, 1);
            timepicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

The value you selected in Timepickerfragment will be provided to onActivityResult, add this in GeneralInfoFragment

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                //do what calculations you want to perform on the received date from timepicker
                break;
        }
    }
}
```