# ANDROID : Using DatePicker from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker

I have a fragment with a TextView in  it. On click of the TextView, I'd like to call a DatePicker in a different fragment and the selected date should be displayed on the TextView in the former fragment.

However, I'm getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.example.vkrishnakumar.finallogin.FlightFragment.onCreate(FlightFragment.java:34)
```

I followed the below link for reference.
[Implementing DatePicker in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923604/implementing-datepicker-in-fragment)

This is my code for the Fragment which contains a TextView.

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FlightFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView depDate;

public FlightFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    depDate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.book_f_dep);
    depDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false);

}
}
```

This is the SelectDateFragment used within the FlightFragment.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {                                 

public SelectDateFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
    populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
}
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    TextView t= (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.book_f_dep);
    t.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
}

}
```

Comment: `R.id.book_f_dep` is null. post the code for the Fragment where you set the id

Comment: problem for `TextView t= (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.book_f_dep);`

Comment: replace getFragmentManager() with getActivity().getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false);
    depDate = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.book_f_dep);
    depDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
});
return root;

}
```

Comment: you should call findView after onCreateView() ， you should have a better understanding of lifecycle of fragment

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, add an explanation of how this will fix the problem...   And not in a comment, edit your answer

Comment: Solved the issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Fragment lifecycle `onCreate` is called before `onCreateView` and therefore you are getting null pointer exception since the view hasn't been populated yet. Override the `onViewCreated` function and add your code there.

Answer (score 1):

In your **FlightFragment** fragment do this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false);

 depDate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.book_f_dep);
    depDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
        }
    });

return rootView;

}
```

In your own code the onCreate is running before onCreateView so the code is throwing **NullPointerException**

Answer (score 0):

**Don't**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false); // Don't do this

}
```

**Do**

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

              View  RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false);

             depDate = (TextView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.book_f_dep); // Problem was here
             return RootView;
    }
```